# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is my found library for image gallery [here!](https://github.com/lawloretienne/ImageGallery)..
I don't know about this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSudY.png

this is my code on gradle

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: 'maven-push.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 15
        versionName "0.0.15"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

}
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that means that you are using wrong version of Java
52 version of Java class files used in Java SE 8

Look at this answer for better explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/3445083

Please recheck java version for `gradle` and your project

In IntelliJ IDEA path to gradle jvm setting is

```
File / Settings / Build Tools / Gradle / Gradle JVM
```

So in Android Studio should be same path to settings

Comment: I found the JVM settings in File > Project Structure > SDK Location